# returning a value from a provision script to vagrant

Tags: vagrant

Is it possible to return a value from a provision script back to vagrant?

```
response = config.vm.provision( "shell", path: "script.sh" )

if response = 'ok'
   do_something
end
```

I couldn't see anything in the vagrant [docs](http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/provisioning/shell.html) describing how this could be done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I am aware I don't think it is possible to return a value like that.

You can however easily get around this by having your provisioning script write a file in the `/vagrant` directory of the guest machine.

You can then use Ruby to process this file which will be in the same folder as your `Vagrantfile`.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to get it from the VMs by doing this way:

**On Windows:**

```
config.trigger.after :provision do |trigger|
    trigger.name = "create token"
    trigger.run = {"inline": "vagrant ssh --no-tty -c 'hostname' master01 > test.txt"}
end
```

**On Mac:**

```
config.trigger.after :provision do |trigger|
  trigger.name = "create token"
  trigger.run = {"inline": "/bin/bash -c 'vagrant ssh --no-tty -c "hostname" master01 > test.txt'"}
end
```

This will dump the output of the command from the VM to the given file in CWD on the host.

Notes:

- About bash redirection - why '/bin/bash -c' is required? (here in case of Mac) -
  https://github.com/hashicorp/vagrant/issues/10674
- I am using Vagrant 2.2.6