# Using Ruby to conditionally reload a vagrant VM between running provisioning scripts

Tags: ruby, vagrant, provisioning

Using the suggestion in [returning a value from a provision script to vagrant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21117246/returning-a-value-from-a-provision-script-to-vagrant), I am running one provisioning script which writes a value to file. I would like Ruby to open this file and conditionally reload the VM depending on what the value is (the `config.vm.provision :reload`  line is achievable by installing a plugin through `vagrant plugin install vagrant-reload`). Then I would like the second provisioning script to run.

I am confused of how and when the Ruby commands are being executed using the code below in my vagrantfile: When the 1st provisioner script completes it goes straight one to the second without printing anything or reloading (the value in requiresreboot.txt is true).

What changes do I need to make for the file processing code to run after the first provisioning script finishes?

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

$script1 = <<SCRIPT
echo "Run this provisioner first to write a value to requiresreboot.txt... "
start-process  "C:\\...\\vagrant_provisioning_file1.bat" -wait
SCRIPT

$script2 = <<SCRIPT
echo "Run this provisioner second... "
start-process  "C:\\...\\vagrant_provisioning_file2.bat" -wait
SCRIPT

Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|

  # Other vagrant setup.....
  # ........................

  File.new("requiresreboot.txt", "w+");

  # Enable provisioning with a shell script 1. 
  config.vm.provision "shell", inline: $script1 

  file = File.open("requiresreboot.txt", "r")
  contents = file.read
  if contents == "max_rearms_reached"
    print "Cannot extend Windows 7 trial: maximum number of rearms reached."
  elsif contents == "true"
    # trigger reload (reboot to apply changes for Windows trial renewal)
    print "Windows trial renewal is required"
    config.vm.provision :reload  
  elsif contents == "false"
    print "No reload required, continuing with provisioning..."  
  end
  file.close

  # Enable provisioning with a shell script 2. 
  config.vm.provision "shell", inline: $script2

end
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run the script from the host machine i would recoment that you use this plugin:

[vagrant-host-shell](https://github.com/phinze/vagrant-host-shell)

If you want to run the script in the guest machine i think you should create a .rb file in the host machine and then copy and execute it inside the guest machine, you can do that doing this:

`config.vm.provision :file, :source => "/path/ruby_script.rb", :destination => "/ruby_script.rb"`

`config.vm.provision :shell, :inline => "ruby /ruby_script.rb"`

To do that you will need ruby installed on the guest machine.

Comment: @allesandro-caetano In either case how would I be able to reload the VM from the external script? i.e. perform the `config.vm.provision :reload`

Comment: @kieran_pli since you're running shell scripts you can just call `vagrant reload` from inside the script. If you're using a ruby script you can just create a subprocess using `IO.popen("vagrant reload")`

Answer (score 0):

> I am confused of how and when the Ruby commands are being executed
>   using the code below in my vagrantfile: When the 1st provisioner
>   script completes it goes straight one to the second without printing
>   anything or reloading (the value in requiresreboot.txt is true).

As you saw the script is run all the way - not line by line. For example vagrant will do all sync folder, etc and then run the provision (provisioning are run in order they written but even if at the beginning of the file it does not mean they will be run as the very first thing) so whats happening is that. So what you have as

```
  file = File.open("requiresreboot.txt", "r")
  contents = file.read
```

is run by vagrant before any provisioning is done. so nothing is printed because contents is empty

ok but it does not answer your question and how can you make it work - honestly I dont know, I tried with [vagrant trigger plugin](https://github.com/emyl/vagrant-triggers) to reload the VM after up command but was not successful. and vagrant does not like to be called from a vagrant command.

vagrant vbguest plugin basically do the same thing that you want to do but they run it from a plugin so have access to all vagrant config. If you really want to do what you want, plugin is probably the best option.