# Vagrantfile: Assign result of inline shell script to variable

Tags: ruby, shell, vagrant, vagrantfile, vagrant-provision

I would like to assign the exit code of an inline shell script in a Vagrantfile to a variable:

```
FOO = config.vm.provision "shell", 
env: {
  "FILE" => "/tmp/hello"
},
inline: <<-SHELL
  [ -f "$FILE" ]; echo $?
SHELL
```

and then use it later in my Vagrantfile, like:

```
if FOO != 0
  ...
```

The way I tried it obviously doesn't work. Does anyone here know

1. if this is possible and
2. if yes, how?

Comment: Sounds related [returning a value from a provision script to vagrant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21117246/returning-a-value-from-a-provision-script-to-vagrant)

Comment: Yes, putting a file into /vagrant is the way I ended up doing it. But still, I wonder if this is possible and I would like to read some references.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using an approach like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21124557/6482759) one.

Something I discovered along the way is that all Ruby conditionals in the Vagrantfile are evaluated in the very beginning, although the inline Shell scripts inside these conditionals (if there are any) are *not* evaluated at the same time. This lead to some strange behavior, which I could avoid by doing like I said above.

Answer (score 0):

After landing here I realized you can actually assign the output of a command exit code as in ruby:

```
FOO = `mycommand`
BAR = $?.exitstatus
```

Then use it in `Vagrantfile` as any other variable.